# Displaying actual values on hover

Tags: reporting, charts

I am making a report that breaks down record types by location.

I would like to add a Stacked to 100% chart comparing the locations, but have the ability for users to hover over each element and get the actual record counts, instead of a percentage. Is there any way to do this?

I can get it to worked using the "Stacked" option, but given size disparty, it makes smaller locations dissappear due to one large location.

Is there any way of getting this to work? Or is the functionality simply not there?